# Extracting columns with similar name from two different csv files

Tags: linux, text-processing, csv-simple

I have two different csv files ,one file contain extended columns names while the other contain a shortcut of the same columns names.

For example :

csv file 1 is :

```
gender,aciclovir drug,aclidinium bromide abc,acenocoumarol drdd
male,2008,2009,2009
```

csv file 2 is :

```
gender,aciclovir,aclidinium bromide,ajmaline
male,2008,2009,2010
```

Now i want to extract columns from file 1 which have a common word with columns from file 2.

desired out put in my example :

```
gender,aciclovir drug,aclidinium bromide abc
male,2008,2009
```

Comment: Are the differences restricted to the addition of the word `drug` in the first file compared to in the second file?

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda no .... it can be any word other than drug. i will edit the names a littlie bit.

Comment: I noticed that seems you started practicing text-processing with this input files but you are all expecting us to ***write code for you***?! what else you tried so far?

Comment: I notice that you have asked several questions but have yet to accept _any_ of the answers you have received. Consider accepting the most helpful answers to each question. Doing so will mark the issue as resolved and increase your chances of getting help in the future. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @αғsнιη sorry to hear that, I am beginner on linux and need to submit my project ( which is mainly in data analysis) in two weeks so i dont have enough time  to study and implement linux code.

Comment: @Solomon123 then you should hire someone on a site like upwork.com or codementor.io to implement it for you as this forum exists to help people with their code not to implement projects for people.

Comment: @EdMorton I just asked 3,4 questions.

Comment: [I see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/554164/solomon123) you haven't [accepted answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to any of your previous questions, and you aren't learning from them as your subsequent questions don't include code from your previous questions that you've tried to modify for your additional problems, and now your questions are getting downvoted for not including any code. You'll get more out of the site if you try to learn from and build upon the answers you get but, as I suggested previously, you can always hire someone to do your project.

Comment: @EdMorton, I can add my trying but it would bias/complicate the answer.

Comment: No, it would get you answers instead of downvotes.

Comment: See also [@Kusalananda's earlier comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741139/extracting-columns-with-similar-name-from-two-different-csv-files?noredirect=1#comment1407993_741139) and the first part of [mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741139/extracting-columns-with-similar-name-from-two-different-csv-files?noredirect=1#comment1408629_741139) for something additional you should do to improve your chances of continuing to get answers - thank people who help you by upvoting and accepting answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -MText::CSV -e '  \

  #read headers of each csv, match column names on first word;
      my $csvA = Text::CSV.new; my $csvB = Text::CSV.new; 
      my $fhA = "csv1.csv".IO.open;  my $fhB = "csv2.csv".IO.open; 
      my @hdrA = $csvA.header($fhA).column-names;  my @hdrB = $csvB.header($fhB).column-names; 
      my %fld = @hdrA.map(*.words[0]) (&) @hdrB.map(*.words[0]);  
      close $fhA; close $fhB;

  #read full csv file into @whole array;
      my $fhA_redux = "csv1.csv".IO.open;
      my @whole; my $csv = Text::CSV.new;
      while $csv.getline($fhA_redux) -> $row {
      @whole.push: $row;
      }; close $fhA_redux;

  #output array that has been @whole>>.[index] filtered for desired columns;
     .join(",").put for @whole>>.[@hdrA.map(*.words[0]).grep(/@(%fld.keys)/, :k)];'
```

Raku is a language in the Perl family of programming languages. It features high-level support for Unicode, and a robust Regex implementation.

Above an external module `Text::CSV` is used to parse CSV. File-handles are defined, as are `Text::CSV.new()` objects. The `$csvA` object is manipulated such that the first (`header`) line of file-handle `$fhA` is parsed into `column-names` and stored as `@hdrA`. Similarly, the `$csvB` object is manipulated such that the first (`header`) line of file-handle `$fhB` is parsed into `column-names` and stored as `@hdrB`.

To get the "intersection" each `@`-sigiled header array is compared to the other using the ASCII "set-intersection" operator `(&)`. If you prefer Unicode symbols here, you can use `∩` instead. The intersection is stored as `%fld` hash.

Note in the comparison (intersection) line, instead of obtaining exact matches you can change the matching criteria by splitting each array element into `words`, and then taking `[0]` to test for matches on the first word of each column. The result is three matching columns:

Sample Inputs:

```
#csv1.csv
gender,aciclovir drug,aclidinium bromide abc,acenocoumarol drdd
male,2008,2009,2009

#csv2.csv
gender,aciclovir,aclidinium bromide,ajmaline
male,2008,2009,2010
```

Sample Output (un-quoted):

```
gender,aciclovir drug,aclidinium bromide abc
male,2008,2009
```

Sample Output (double-quoted, add `>>.raku` to the very end of the last line of the code above):

```
"gender","aciclovir drug","aclidinium bromide abc"
"male","2008","2009"
```

If you need to output `csv`, the markdown document below instructs like so:

```
# and write CSV file, filtered as above
my $fh_out = open "new.csv", :w;
$csv.say($fh_out, $_) for @whole>>.[@hdrA.map(*.words[0]).grep(/@(%fld.keys)/, :k)];
$fh_out.close;
```

https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/doc/Text-CSV.md
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the header in both files is a simple list of comma-delimited field names, without any special CSV quoting, we may extract the field names on separate lines from a file using

```bash
head -n 1 file | tr , '\n'
```

or, with `sed`,

```bash
sed -e 'y/,/\n/' -e q file
```

Further assuming that none of the field names contains characters that are special in regular expressions (`.`, `[`, `*`, `\`, `^` (at the start of a field name), and `$` (at the end of a field name)), we can use this to create a set of regular expressions from `file2` that would match the start of the field names in `file1` (inserting `^` at the start of each line would do this):

```bash
head -n 1 file2 | tr , '\n' | sed 's/^/^/'
```

or, with `sed`,

```bash
sed -e 'y/,/\n/' -e q file2 | sed 's/^/^/'
```

or, with a single `sed` invocation,

```bash
sed -e 'y/,/\n/' -e 's/^/^/' -e 's/\n/&^/g' -e q file2
```

or, with GNU `sed`,

```bash
sed -e 's/^/^/' -e 's/,/\n^/g' -e q file2
```

We may apply these expressions to the list of field names from `file1` to get the ones from that file that should be extracted:

```bash
grep -f <( head -n 1 file2 | tr , '\n' | sed 's/^/^/' ) <( head -n 1 file1 | tr , '\n' )
```

The result of this, given the data that you show in your question, will be the following list:

```
gender
aciclovir drug
aclidinium bromide abc
```

Note that this list may contain duplicate entries if a field name in `file2` match multiple field names in `file1`.

We may then create a comma-delimited list of these field names and use it as an argument to the `cut` sub-command of [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to finally extract the wanted fields from `file1`:

```bash
mlr --csv cut -f "$( grep -f <( head -n 1 file2 | tr , '\n' | sed 's/^/^/' ) <( head -n 1 file1 | tr , '\n' ) | tr '\n' , )" file1
```

This would give us

```
gender,aciclovir drug,aclidinium bromide abc
male,2008,2009
```

Comment: Thank you that's a great explanation and answer I really appreciate your help. But this solution gives me an output that return one column less . (return  all common column except last one).

Comment: @Solomon123 It might do if your input files are DOS text files. Convert them into Unix text files using `dos2unix`.